# Set flex contianer height to equal the height of the smallest flex item

Tags: css, height, flexbox

I have the following code, I want to set the container height to the height of the 
smaller flex item so that I can hide the extra content in larger flex item.

Basically:
smaller flex item has some text,
larger flex item has only a image.

IDEA is to reveal parts image as the text in the smaller flex item grows

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.smaller-flex-item {
  order: 1;
}
.larger-flex-item {
  order: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="smaller-flex-item">Unknown height</div>
  <div class="larger-flex-item">Known Height</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

I'll ty to answer this best I can. I can only think of two ways. Well you could try something like:

---

```
.smaller-flex-item {
order: 1;
max-height: 200px;
}
.larger-flex-item {
order: 2;
max-height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

Also you could change `.larger-flex-item` the `max-height: 200px;` to `max-height: inherit;`.

I hope that helped you!